# Angular, show content in a modal for a browsing user but show content on a new page for a new user

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to show the same content (with the same url) in a modal to users who are already on my site browsing, but on a new page for new users.

For example here the user journey on canopy:

Go to https://canopy.co/ and click on a link. Content is loaded in a modal with the url updated to https://canopy.co/products/12309
However go straight to https://canopy.co/products/12309 and it loads it on it's own view, without a modal.

How can I do this with angular? I've tried a load of things with ui-router and multiple views but it ends up being rendered twice.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably several approaches to this. This is mine.

### Outline

When the state changes, we want to check whether we could potentially serve the content within a modal over the current view, rather than replacing the current view entirely. We'll define this in our routing config - views that can host a modal will have a `modalMaster` flag, and views that can be displayed within a modal will have a `modalSlave` flag.

We'll use `ui.router`'s `$stateChangeStart` event to intercept the state changes, and cancel them as necessary, this is where we'll open the modal.

### Challenges

- We need to maintain a knowledge of the state of a modal, if there is one
- Preventing a state change also prevents the URL changing, so we need to do that manually
- Using the browser back button should close the modal and take us back to the state beneath it.

### Code

Note that all code is in coffeescript and jade, I find it much neater. If you need to transcribe, use [js2coffee.org](http://js2coffee.org/).

#### Router config:

```
.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)->

  # Add details on which templates can open models containing which other 
  # templates.
  $stateProvider.state 'shop',
    url: '/'
    templateUrl: 'shop.html'
    modalMaster: true

  $stateProvider.state 'item',
    url: '/item/{id}'
    templateUrl: 'item.html'
    modalSlave: true

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  # Enable handling of url changes ourselves.
  $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept()
```

The last line is important as it allows us to stop the url changes updating the view later on.

#### State and URL event listeners

```
.run ($rootScope, $state, $modal, $location, $urlRouter, $timeout)->   
  # set some flags for use later.
  modalInstance = toStatePrevented = entering = null    
  # Intercept state changes - if we're in a modal master and we're going to a
  # modal slave, open a modal containing the slave state instead.
  $rootScope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (event, toState, toParams, fromState)->
    if fromState.modalMaster and toState.modalSlave
      event.preventDefault()
      # set a property to show which state is currently in the modal
      $state.current.inModal = toState
      entering = true # for url handling
      $timeout -> # change url manually
        $location.path($state.href(toState, toParams), false)
      , 0 # the 0 timeout makes sure the preventDefault doesn't stop url 
          # change
      # open a modal containing the new state, you can merge this with 
      # modal specific properties like "resolve" etc. if you want them
      modalInstance = $modal.open(toState)
      # clear our flags when the modal closes - this only uses dismiss so we
      # only need "catch" right now.
      modalInstance.result.catch(()->
        modalInstance = toStatePrevented = $state.current.inModal = 
          entering = null
        $state.go(fromState)
      )

  $rootScope.$on '$locationChangeSuccess', (event, toUrl, fromUrl)->
    event.preventDefault()
    # if there is nothing in a modal, just handle as normal
    if !$state.current.inModal? then $urlRouter.sync()
    # dismiss modal if url changes and modal is visible
    else if not entering and modalInstance? then modalInstance.dismiss()
    # if we are opening a modal, set a flag so that next time the url changes
    # we will dismiss it.
    else entering = false
```

The comments should explain most of this. In practise you will probably need a bit more than what is here - for example, you should make sure the case that a link has been clicked from inside the modal is handled correctly, but this should get you started.

Naturally, I have made a plunker to demonstrate this solution **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xEQmdkVUCIJvybuSjfQR?p=preview)**, but make sure you use the "launch preview in a separate window" functionality to see everything working to its full effect.

### Result

Navigating from `shop` to `item` opens a modal, but navigating directly to `item` via a URL opens the item on its own as the `ui-view`.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks ed. I've got an issue with getting an id from the url. I tried to pass it to the modal through resolve but then it doesn't exist for the separate page.

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: itemIdProvider <- itemId`

Comment: I've updated the plunker, adding lines `15-19` and `47`. You were probably getting the error because you were asking a resolve result to be injected into your controller, without a resolve property in the route definition. My fix was to include a resolved property in the route definition that takes the `id` from `$stateParams`. Since we're not actually in that state we had to artificially set the `$stateParams` before opening the modal. You may want to revert to whatever params were present before after the modal closes (I didn't include this).

Comment: Thanks I was looking for that ! that's genius ! I have one question, I have a controller A where I `$state.go` to open the modal, but how I can I send my A controller scope data to the modal resolve to send then to the modal controller B ? Hope it is clear :)

Comment: Set the resolve property on `toState` on this line: `modalInstance = $modal.open(toState)`